# Azure File share mounted drive showing Disconnected Network Drive

Tags: powershell, azure-sdk-.net

I am using Microsoft Azure Fluent API with RunPowerShellScript method to execute powershell script.
My file share drive mounted properly but it's showing disconnected .But same powershell command when i run from virtual machine it's working properly.Please see below image :

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @Newton Not yet

Comment: hmm, i have run into the exact same problem, i have used both the RestAPI and Azure SDK, and both ways the same issue. i will post back if i get a solution.

Comment: I am also finding solution.Please post back if you got.

Comment: OP or @NewtonSheikh, have you found a solution ? I have the same issue